# NOIR Camera V2.1 not working in the dark

Tags: camera, raspicam, raspberry-pi-os

The camera used to work with pink shade in the morning and even in the dark without additional leds the last time used. I recently used it after a long time on a new system and noticed that it was working like a normal camera with no pink shade but didnt work in the dark.

I tried the blue filter that came along to test but it was just dark wherein it used to work before.

[image: without any filter in daytime]
[image: daytime with blue filter]
[image: in dark]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Any idea why it is not working anymore? Is it a software update or is the camera defective.